# Action not being performed on Task

Tags: c#, async-await

I am attempting to use aysnc/await and I am having trouble getting past step 1. When I run the following code, my expectation is that "myMethod" will be called with "Bob" passed and then "Hello Bob" will be displayed on the page.Nothing happens when I run it. I debugged it and the "myMethod" does not get called.

What am I missing?

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myMethod("Bob")).ContinueWith(t => Label1.Text = t.Result, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());                                                             
    }        

    public string myMethod(string name)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
```

Comment: ASP.Net does not work like that; your response has already been served.  You want to run on the client.

Comment: Also, you should be careful to [never use `Task.Factory.StartNew` without passing in a task scheduler](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), you can easily accidentally run code on a scheduler you did not intend to. You should just use `Task.Run` instead (Not that using `Task.Run` will solve your problem)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are working with asp.net. If so, you should know about [Page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). At the time, when your task will finished, page is probably already processed and response already returned to client. So even if your code will executed, it does not make any sense at that moment.